# jQuery: <h> treated as <p> in jquery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

A simple example is confusing me about selector in jQuery. 
I have this html code:

```
<div class="container">
   <h1>Welcome to my Website </h1>
   <p>First paragraph</p>
   <p>Second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

if I want to highlight the second paragrah I think that this is the right way:

```
$('p:nth-child(2)').css("background-color","yellow");
```

But this is not correct, in fact the First paragraph will be highlighted, even if I have only two `<p>` section and I'm putting the value 2 inside the `nth-child()` function.

[Here the related jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/527Rm/1/)

If I remove the `<h1>` element, the second paragraph will be highlighted. So, it seems as if the `<h1>` element is treated as `<p>` element by jQuery selector.

However the code:

`$('p:nth-child(1)').css("background-color","yellow");`

will not highlight anything. Why this happens?

Comment: I don't really like those pseudo selectors, and if it where me, I'd do `$('p').eq(1).css(...`

Comment: @adeneo Why you call them "pseudo selectors"?

Comment: They are selectors, but technically in CSS they're in a category known as ["pseudo-classes"](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes). The term "pseudo-selectors" is probably a corruption of the phrase "pseudo-class selectors".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nth-child` means literally "child in place **n**", what you're searching is `nth-of-type` , have a look: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/
So this will work as you expect:

```
$('p:nth-of-type(2)').css("background-color","yellow");
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t2rn7/

Answer (score 3):

`:nth-child` is with respect to the parent, so in your first example that `<p>` is in fact the 2nd child.  If you want it to be the second *p*, you should use [`:nth-of-type`](http://api.jquery.com/?s=%3anth-of-type)